# List of URIs registered to FakeWeb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fakeweb

Is there a way to get a list of registered URIs in [FakeWeb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb)? When I register one like:

```
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, url, body: expected_response)
```

It seems like it should be available somewhere since [it keeps track of it internally](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb/blob/master/lib/fake_web/registry.rb), but I can't track it down externally. Something like `FakeWeb.registered_uris`, but obviously that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
FakeWeb::Registry.instance.uri_map
```

This returns a nested hash with `FakeWeb::Responder` objects.

When you register a uri with #register_uri, FakeWeb creates a `FakeWeb::Responder` which holds the uri, which is then stored within the `FakeWeb::Registry` singleton.

You finally have to iterate the result map and get the uri's out of it:

```
FakeWeb::Registry.instance.uri_map.map { |_, v| v.map { |_, w| w } }.flatten.collect { |e| e.uri }.uniq
```

Hope this helps.